# Using Calculate Field in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: field-calculator, sql, arcgis-pro, python-parser

I have several field in an attribute table that have  value, I am wanting to using the 'Calculate Field' GP tool to select the  values and replace them with zero.

Anyone have any ideas on the Python and/or SQL statement I would use to execute this?

[image: Attribute Table with Field]

This is the Calculate Field GP

[image]

I tried this but it is not working

[image]

Comment: Did you take a look at this http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm?  What's did you try that is not working?

Comment: So I tried this https://imgur.com/AjC198D but it is not working. I have no experience with Python so its all a learning curve

Comment: do this...https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000004254

Comment: I was able to get it thank you! How would I make this work across all fields?

Comment: That's a different question you might want to modify the OP now that you have a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: If you found a solution, please include it as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.

Comment: Please always include code as formatted text rather than only as a picture.